# Google Docs for Android App. Open Source?

Tags: android, open-source

Are Android applications like Google Calender, Google Docs, Google Goggles, Android Market open source? I want to implement a similar UI and back end for my application. Can somebody tell me how to get the open source projects code from GOOGLE. Please let me know any kind of details related to this. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out https://github.com/android/

[Calendar code](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_calendar)

[EDIT]: Updated links

Comment: I did not find snything like gdocs? Does this mean it is not open source? Can you guide me to a application that has good implementation of listview and another one for REST client with sync adapter implementation. Thank you for the help.

Comment: How about the gmail app? Is that also not open source?

Comment: I assume it would be there too (http://android.git.kernel.org/).

Comment: I tried searching for it. Can you please get the link for gdocs and gmail please. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Funny what was preventing you from finding it? Anyhow I don't believe the Docs app is open source. Email may be this http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Email.git;a=commit;h=a5c3744a247e432acf9f571a9dfb55321c4baa1a

Comment: link doesn't work... @source.rar

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth checking out the K-9 mail client for Android.
It has a pretty decent UI IMO.
[K-9 Mail Project on Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/k9mail/)